# I'm facing black screen after making call with agora sdk in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, call, agora.io

Note: I'm using the CreateWithConfig method since RtcEngine.create is deprecated.

E/MethodChannel#agora_rtc_engine(21216): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#agora_rtc_engine(21216): java.lang.RuntimeException: NEED TO check rtc sdk init fatal error
E/MethodChannel#agora_rtc_engine(21216):
E/MethodChannel#agora_rtc_engine(21216): at io.agora.agorartcengine.AgoraRtcEnginePlugin.onMethodCall(AgoraRtcEnginePlugin.java:113)
E/MethodChannel#agora_rtc_engine(21216): at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#agora_rtc_engine(21216): at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#agora_rtc_engine(21216): at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:818)
E/MethodChannel#agora_rtc_engine(21216): at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#agora_rtc_engine(21216): at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
E/MethodChannel#agora_rtc_engine(21216): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
E/MethodChannel#agora_rtc_engine(21216): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
E/MethodChannel#agora_rtc_engine(21216): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#agora_rtc_engine(21216): at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
E/MethodChannel#agora_rtc_engine(21216): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)***emphasized text***

Answer (score 0):

This error is mainly caused when you're using an invalid App Id or a wrong format. You can try to generate another App Id and then test it out.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone facing blackScreen problem just initialize agora by adding this line:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  initAgora();
}
void initAgora() async {
  await _client.initialize();
}
```

example link: https://pub.dev/packages/agora_uikit/example